# I am trying to create a vector of classes and then name each class with a for loop

Tags: c++, loops, vector, std

I am very new at this.  All help will be greatly appreciated.
I am trying to create a vector of class objects and then name each object with a for loop. I get error c2679: binary '>>' no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' on line 35.  cin >> play.p_name. Please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Player
{
private:
    string player_name;
    int score[18];
public:
    void p_name(string);
    void Player::p_name();
};

void Player::p_name(string name)
{
    player_name = name;
}

int main()
{
    int num_players = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    cout << "Please enter number of players.\n";
    cin >> num_players;

    vector<Player>player_vector;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_players ; ++i)
    {
        Player play;
        player_vector.push_back(play);
        for (int j = 0; j < num_players; j++)
        {
            cout << "What is the name of Player " << j << ": ";
            cin >> play.p_name;
        }
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect that line to do?

Comment: I guess i expected it to input a name to that vector.

Comment: Your cin >> play.p_name; is making a function call, while cin is expecting a variable type, you cannot pass a function call to cin. I think you ment to say: cin >> play.player_name; another problem you have is that, I think you are trying to call Player Objects that you have already stored in your vector and assign them names, so you need to: ((player_vector.at(j)).p_name(cin >> play.player_name));

Comment: BTW, you're not creating a "vector of classes".  Creating classes is what you do when you write things like `class Player { ... }` in your source code.  Creating *objects* (which are *instances* of classes) is what your program does when it runs.  You're creating a vector of `Player` objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First**, `play.p_name` is a function, not a variable; you can't assign to it like that.  You have to call it with a string variable as an argument.  You could do something like:

```
string name;
cin >> name;
play.p_name(name);
```

**Second**, the `Player` object where you're storing the name is not the one that's in the vector!

When you do `player_vector.push_back(play)`, you're putting a *copy* of the `play` object into the vector.  Since `play` hasn't been assigned a name yet, the copy in the vector has no name either.

Later, you store a name in `play`, but that doesn't affect the one stored in the vector.  And at the bottom of the loop, `play` gets destroyed and a new one (with no name) is constructed for the next iteration.  So the name you store in `play` just gets thrown away.

You should move the `player_vector.push_back(play)` line down to *after* you set the player's name, so that you're copying an object that has a name instead of one that doesn't.

**Third**, you don't need the two nested loops.  Prompting for the names in a loop just means that for each individual player (counted by `i`), you'll ask for the names of *every* player (counted by `j`).  If there are 5 players, the user will be asked for 25 names.

Get rid of the `j` loop, and just ask for the player's name in the `i` loop, right after creating the `play` object.

**Also**, you have a syntax error in your class definition:  the line `void Player::p_name();` should just be `void p_name();`.  You only use the `Player::` qualifier to refer to the function from *outside* the class (such as when you define the function a few lines later).  Within the class definition, you don't have to tell the compiler that `p_name` is in the `Player` class because the compiler knows that already.

**Lastly**, you don't need the `int i = 0` and `int j = 0` variables declared at the top of `main`.  You're not actually using those variables at all, since you define *new* `i` and `j` variables in the `for` loops.  (And of course, you don't need `j` at all, as explained above.)

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I only put int i and j = 0 because the compiler gave me uninitialized variable errors, I'm sure because of my other flaws.  I am 3 weeks in and i have not had the ah hah moment for classes yet but i hope that finally asking a question to smarter people than I will make that happen.